# change UIButton title without fade effect or animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button that contains different titles that depends on the app's circumstances. The problem is that every time it changes it happens with an unwanted animation. I change it using the next line of code:

```
self.nextLevelButton.setTitle("Next Level", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I have tried:

```
self.nextLevelButton.layoutifneeded()
```

and:

```
uiview.setAnimaionsEnabled(false)
self.nextLevelButton.setTitle("Next Level", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
uiview.setAnimaionsEnabled(true)
```

None of the above is working.

Comment: I saw that question, nevertheless it is for objective C and  the solutions for them aren't working for swift.

Comment: It is trivial to covert to swift -  UIView.performWithoutAnimation { () -> Void in
            self.myButton.setTitle(newTitle, forState: .Normal)
            self.myButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        }  I just tested this and it is fine.

Comment: I have added a Swift equivalent answer.  The `setAnimationsEnabled` false/true version also works in Swift

Comment: I detected the problem, the uibutton must be in custom mode and not in system.